# Gpu connected components labeling (blob detection)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gpu

What is the state of the art regarding GPU CCL? Is there an open source gpu blob detection?
I am familiar with opencv however the speed is crucial for my app.
Thanks

Comment: http://hpcg.purdue.edu/bbenes/papers/Stava2011CCL.pdf

Comment: @rwong  2 years since this question. Does OpenCv included a GPU version of the blob detection algorithm?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez: I don't do any work on GPU at all. I was just pointing out the theoretical possibility. Nowadays for standardized image processing library on GPU, one would take a look at OpenVX. OpenCV is also moving toward (i.e. delegating to) OpenVX for the GPU processing.

Comment: @rwong thanks for your reply.